# Removing collected charges in a IC CMOS circuit exposed under a 30keV electron beam source

Tags: mosfet, radiation, electron, uv

I would like to know if there is any mechanism (for example UV light exposition) to remove charges collected in an IC CMOS circuit that was exposed under a 30keV electron beam source. Presumably, those charges were collected in the MOS oxides.

The CMOS circuit is a photodiode-based Image Sensor and some pixels appear as always illuminated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to heat it up to the maximum storage temp and hope the trapped charge eventually tunnels out.  No idea if that will actually work in your case.

Comment: Another guess-- UV exposure (lower limit on the wavelength may be limited by the package window material).

Comment: I think you should consider that you may have trapped charge in the gate oxides, increased surface states at the oxide/silicon interface, and/or increased leakage in the photodiodes. Some of these effects can be annealed with time and temperature, but some are more or less permanent. Whether or not the device was powered while irradiated could also make a difference. It's hard to give a definitive answer based on a sample of one.

Comment: You can also try decharging it with low voltage AC like it’s done in LCD's with software, but if it was always like this, then it’s a defect.

Answer (score 2):

- back in the early 90’s my boss indicated they used a UV EPROM with a lens to take a macro picture and it worked although not very well.

Similarity you make be correct to think that saturating the charges in a [UVEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPROM) is like erasing a stuck pixel in your image sensor. **As long as the polarity is the opposite to the charge or leakage voltage being detected**, in theory it may work.

But if you flood it with too much energy, the voltage may breakdown, conduct more current and dissipate heat in a pixel.  I have used an SEM to burn pinholes in ceramic when focused for fun when examining ceramic HDD heads for 14” disk drives in the early ‘80’s like a nano arc welder. Then zooming out with charge clouds slowly migrating across the insulated surface from the macro view that looked like a fog rolling in under an ultra low vacuum.